# What URL should be used to create/Modify OIM user via REST API SCIM for UDF?

Tags: rest, identity, udf, oim

I am trying to create and modify users using SCIM/REST API's available OOTB in 11gR2PS3.

I am able to create/modify users for all the OOTB attributes specfied in the [document](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E52734_01/oim/OMDEV/scim.htm#OMDEV5526)

As per the documentation, these API's are supported for custom UDFs as well.

Does anyone know what the schema attributes name and format that needs to be passed in the content body for custom UDF's?

As per the documentation

> Note: You can use user defined fields (UDFs) in SCIM requests. After
>   UDFs are created in Oracle Identity Manager, they automatically appear
>   in SCIM resources as regular attributes. There is no difference in the
>   requests and responses with regular attributes.

when we crate the user even after specifying the UDF value its not going in OIM DB and it also doesn't throw any exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. call `/Schemas`operation using `get` method 
   using your OIM URL :`http://<host>:<port>/idaas/im/scim/v1/Schemas`

   2. Use the returned schema while using create, update operation on the UDF.

e.g. schema returned is `urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:oracle:2.0:OIG:User`

then qualify UDF with the returned schema while calling Create/Update operation.

```
"urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:oracle:2.0:OIG:User":{
UDFNAME : UDFVALUE
}
```

also incluede the schema in the `schemas[]` if its not there already.